# ConstraintLayout - Align view to top or bottom of another view, depending on the visibility of the other view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have the following simplified XML layout with one constraint layout, two textviews and one switch:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Demo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/innerConstraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/switch1" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

For `switch1` I have to use `layout_constraintTop_toTopOf` and `layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` to center it horizontally with `textView1`. Otherwise `switch1` would be too big.

`textView2` should be visible below `switch1` if `switch1` is visible and otherwise aligned with the top of `textView1`.

[image]

How an I achieve this?

Currently `textView2` is visible below `switch1` if `switch1` is visible but otherwise aligned with the bottom of `textView1`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the top and bottom constraints of the switch to center it on the left *TextVIew*. When the switch is visible, the bottom *TextView* is aligned to its bottom. When the switch is `gone`, you want the bottom *TextView* to be aligned to the top of the left *TextView*. (The switch actually extends below and above the left *TextView* but appears to shrink since it is centered on the left view.

A *Barrier* positioned below the switch with the top of the bottom *TextView* attached to is will get you what you want when the switch is visible. But what happens when the switch is `gone`?

When the switch is made `gone`, it, in essence' shrinks to a point. Since the top and bottom of the switch is still attached to the top and bottom of the left *TextView*, the point will be centered between the top and bottom of the left *TextView*. This is not what you want since you want the bottom view to be aligned with the top of the left view.

The way around this is to set a zero width/height widget on top of the left *TextView*. A [Space](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space) widget is the most appropriate.

We can now set a barrier to the bottoms of the *Space* and the switch. We will also need to specify that the switch is to be ignored by the *Barrier* when the switch is made `gone` by specifying

```
app:barrierAllowsGoneWidgets="false"
```

Here is what the final layout looks like. I have made a few adjustments for this demo.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="32dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="This is the left TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Bottom TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/spacerTop"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView1" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierAllowsGoneWidgets="false"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="spacerTop,switch1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

I don't recall when some of the features I reference were introduced. You may need to move to a later version of *ConstraintLayout* to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Barrier` for such conditions. Try following code.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:text="Demo"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/barrier"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:barrierDirection="left"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView2, switch1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/switch1" />
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this now aligns `textView2` to the middle of `textView1` but still not to the top if `switch1` is invisible.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make the switch1 visibility to gone in the class instead of making it invisible

```
         switch1.visibility = VIEW.GONE
```

and the textview2 will jump and take its place after textview1

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, but no this will not work since `textView2` will use the `layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` of the hidden `switch1` instead of the `layout_constraintTop_toTopOf`.